# Using Ember.js text field ids for a <label> tag

Tags: templates, ember.js

A label tag is of the form:

```
<label for="id_of_text_field">
<input type="text" name="example" id="id_of_text_field" />
```

Where the `for` tag of the label and the `id` tag of the text field need to match.  I had two ideas to make this work in my Ember.js template:

**Idea #1:** I tried to make a special binding named `field_id` to use in both the `label` and the `TextField`. I executed this as follows:

```
<label {{bindAttr for="content.field_id"}}> {{content.label}}</label>
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="content.data" id="content.field_id"}}
```

Unfortunately only the `label's` id renders correctly. The `TextField's` id does **not** render correctly and turns out to be "metemorph... something-or-other".

**Idea #2:** To somehow conjure the TextField's id and use that for the label tag, but I'm afraid at some point the TextField's id will not be ready when the label tag is rendered.  Even if this were not an issue, I do not know how to find the `TextField's` id from JS.

This is in a template so I will have more than one of these label/TextField pairs.

How can I get the label's `for` tag to match up with the TextField's `id` tag with Ember.js?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

Using Peter Wagenet's advice and slight modification, I did the following:

```
<label {{bindAttr for="textField.elementId"}}> {{content.label}}</label>
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="content.value" viewName="textField"}}
```

Using this technique users can now click labels to select TextFields, CheckBoxes, and Selects.

Comment: For latest Ember (1.4.0-beta.6) you need to use `for="view.textField.elementId"` instead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First off, the Metamorph tag is for the label's value. It's not related to the field's id. However, this code still won't work because standard properties don't do anything special with property paths. In this case, the value of `id`, is literally `content.field_id`. This is certainly not what you wanted. In normal circumstances, you could use `elementIdBinding` (`id` is just an alias for `elementId`), however the element ids for Ember Views cannot be changed after creation so that approach won't work here.

One possible solution makes use of the `viewName` property. The `viewName` property provides a named reference to the view on the `parentView`. You could then, do the following:

```
<label {{bindAttr for="view.textField.field_id"}}> {{content.label}}</label>
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="content.data" viewName="textField"}}
```

Comment: I think http://jsfiddle.net/GtsKK/2/ is a full demonstration of what shs is going for. You want to bind "for" to textField.elementId, not field_id, since the TextField view won't have that attribute. Also, you can't just use the TextField class on its own since its name attribute doesn't bind anything, and in order for it to be a valid form, you have to provide a name for each of your inputs, so I subclassed TextField and added the missing name attribute binding.

Comment: Sorry for the edits... so I set the template to: <label {{bindAttr for="textField.elementId"}}> {{content.label}}</label>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="content.data" viewName="textField"}} and that's it.  The **for** and **id** tags are now matching up.  No JS required.  Very nice!  I changed your 'field_id' to 'elementId'.  Seems too easy.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would I get ahold of 'parentView' from inside the content.field_id computed value?  From inside field_id: function() {} I tried a variety of get|getPath() with 'view', 'this.view', 'parentView', 'this.parentView', and they all came back null or undefined.

Comment: @shs If you can provide a fiddle of what you're trying to do that would help.

Comment: I ended up just binding directly to elementId per your suggestion.  My question was more of a side-note:  As I learn ember the hardest part is getting to the value I need where I need it.  But I'm getting the hang of it.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get this working... I suspect that this is due to using the above snippet within a {{#each}} tags. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems not to work in ember-1.0 anymore. See this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ufevoh/2/edit

Comment: @DarylTeo I'm having the same problem. Have you had any revelations since your post?
@PeterWagenet Any suggestions for how to get this working in an `{{#each}}` loop? For instance, labels "test1" and "test2" both end up pointing at the last input element: http://jsbin.com/ufevoh/4/edit

Comment: @DarylTeo If you're still looking for a solution, try replacing your {{#each}} block with a {{#collection}} block like so: http://jsbin.com/ufevoh/7/edit

Answer (score 5):

This won't always solve your problem, but I just wanted to add that simply nesting the input inside the label is often a convenient solution, since it allows you to drop the `for` attribute altogether ([reference](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element)).

Comment: Interesting.  I was planning on laying out controls in a table with labels in one column and controls in the other.

Comment: Do you know what the browser support for this is? With a quick trial it seems to work well in Firefox and Chrome. I don't have IE handy...

Comment: I don't know. It seems to be a common pattern though, so I'd assume it's widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

Here was my solution to this problem from a while back:

```
App.Widget.TextField = Em.ContainerView.extend({
    tagName: '',
    type: 'text',
    label: null,
    value: null,
    valueSize: '30px',

    childViews: ['labelView', 'inputView'],

    labelView: Em.View.extend({
        tagName: 'label',
        attributeBindings: ['for'],

        forBinding: 'parentView.inputView.elementId',

        init: function () {
            this.set('defaultTemplate', Em.Handlebars.compile(this.getPath('parentView.label')));
            this._super();
        }
    }),

    inputView: Em.TextField.extend({
        typeBinding: 'parentView.type',
        sizeBinding: 'parentView.valueSize',
        valueBinding: 'parentView.value'
    })
});
```

Then from within a Handlebars template:

```
{{view App.Widget.TextField label="Some Label"}}
```