# Ember.js TextField id for label tag with ember router

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a form that I am building in an Ember.js app that requires the `<label>` tags be separate from the `<input>` tags. This has created a problem b/c I cannot seem to bind the `for=""` attribute of the `<label>` tag correctly.

I have looked at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468164/using-ember-js-text-field-ids-for-a-label-tag) and the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GtsKK/2/) in the solution's comments, but it doesn't seem to work with apps that use the `Ember.Router` architecture

Here is my fiddle exemplifying the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/wmarbut/jKGMW/

I would **very muchly prefer** not to use any solution that requires me to make actual entries into either my view or controller object for each individual form field.

The quick and dirty of the code can be seen here

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <!-- XXX: How do I bind the "for" attribute correctly? -->
            <label {{bindAttr for="curUser.elementId"}}>Current User</label>
        </th>
        <td>    
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="current_user.first_name" viewName="curUser"}}   
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently you need to explicitly access the element at its namespace with `view.`

This fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/wmarbut/jKGMW/5/

updated code would be

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        <!-- XXX: This now works -->
        <label {{bindAttr for="view.curUser.elementId"}}>Current User</label>
    </th>
    <td>    
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="current_user.first_name" viewName="curUser"}}   
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: And how would this work when your text field is dynamically generated, meaning you can not call it `curUser`?

Comment: @Cimm You'd need to dynamically generate a deterministic value for the `viewName` property at the same time that you generate your dynamically generated field.

Comment: Directly using Ember.Textfield has been deprecated since Ember 1.7. Instead using it as an input helper is recommended. How will we access the view in `label` as {{input}} helper doesn't have an attribute that accepts `viewnName` @wmarbut, @sly7_7