# dynamic value in template

Tags: ember.js

I'have extended a View (with a fieldId generator function) and set the following template:

I need to have the same computed id for the label "for attribute" ( computed with view.fieldId) and the {{view Em.Textfield ...}}

How to set the id attribute with view.fieldId in the {{view Em.TextField expression..}} ?

Any other alternative ?

```
template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<label class="control-label" {{bindAttr for="view.fieldId"}}>{{view.label}}</label>\
                     <div class="controls">\
                     {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="view.value" class="input-large"}}\
                     <span class="help-inline">Something may have gone wrong</span>\
                     </div>')
```

Comment: All my questions has been updated with rating. Tx for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to bind the `for` attribute of the `<label>` to the `elementId` property of the `Ember.TextField`.

First, you have to give a name to your Ember.TextField by settings its `viewName` property:

```
{{view Ember.TextField viewName="myTextField"}}
```

Then, you have to bind its `elementId` to the `for` attribute, using `bindAttr`:

```
<label {{bindAttr for="view.myTextField.elementId"}}> My label </label>
```

And it works, just [try it in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ah3z/).

N.B.: There is one other solution is to nest the `input` inside the label. For more information, take a look at [this SO question: Using Ember.js text field ids for a  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468164/using-ember-js-text-field-ids-for-a-label-tag)