# Ember tabular form with objects for rows and property names for columns

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to create a modular tabular form that takes an input of 1) an array of objects (the rows) and 2) an array of property names of those objects (the columns). Through these two arrays, it should retrieve properties that can be modified through Ember.TextFields in the form.

I cannot figure out how to do this. I can retrieve the values of the properties (as shown in the code below) but they are raw values, rather than references, so the bindings to these do not update the objects' properties.

### View

```
App.SomeTabularForm = Em.View.extend({
  template: <see below>,

  things: [
    Em.Object.create({ foo: 'a', bar: 'b' }), 
    Em.Object.create({ foo: 1, bar: 2 })
  ],
  fieldNames: ['bar', 'foo'],

  thingsWithFields: function() {
    var fieldNames = this.get('fieldNames');

    var thingWithFieldsProxy = Em.ObjectProxy.extend({
      fields: function() {
        var thing = this;

        return fieldNames.map(function(fn) {
          // FIX: this returns a raw value which is not bindable in a template
          return thing.get(fn);
        });
      }.property()
    });

    return this.get('things').map(function(t) {
      return thingWithFieldsProxy.create({ content: t });
    });
  }.property('things.[]', 'fields.[]')
});
```

### Template

```
<table>
  <tr>
    {{#each view.fieldNames}}
      <th>{{this}}</th>
    {{/each}}
  <tr>

  {{#each view.thingsWithFields}}
    <tr>
      {{#each fields}}
        <td>
          {{! FIX: does not actually bind to thing's property }}
          {{input type="text" valueBinding="this"}}
        </td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  {{#each}}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify template name,

```
App.SomeTabularForm  = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: "mytemp",
....
```

the template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="mytemp">
    {{blah}}
    <table>
  <tr>
    {{#each view.fieldNames}}
      <th>{{this}}</th>
    {{/each}}....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EdWG3/3/

If you want to use the template property,

```
App.SomeTabularForm  = Em.View.extend({
    template: Em.Handlebars.compile("<div>{{#each field in view.fieldNames}}{{field}}<br/>{{/each}}</div>"),

  things: [...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EdWG3/4/

If you use it in the context of routing then you need to modify the name of the view,
http://jsfiddle.net/EdWG3/2/

**EDIT**

In order to bind to the proxy objects

the template needs to modified as follows,

```
{{#each view.thingsWithFields}}
    <tr>

        <td>
          {{! FIX: does not actually bind to thing's property }}
          {{input type="text" valueBinding="content.bar"}}{{input type="text" valueBinding="content.foo"}}
        </td>

    </tr>
      {{/each}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EdWG3/7/

Comment: Hello melc, thanks for the help, but this is not the issue. The issue is that I cannot modify the objects' properties through the form. I have updated the fiddle to demonstrate this (also fixed a couple trivial mistakes): http://jsfiddle.net/EdWG3/5/

Comment: Ok, now i see what you are trying to do. Although i find it a little complicated, it does not work because you are trying to bind to a string value not an ember object. Modified, http://jsfiddle.net/EdWG3/7/  to work with the proxy objects.

Comment: Is there a way to iterate over the fields rather than explicitly referring to them in the template? For example, if you changed `fieldNames` to `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`, the table would not match anymore.

Comment: One way of doing this without modifying the template you have, would be to dynamically create the template part related to the input fields. In order to make it more clear, i moved all model related stuff to a controller and created a second view that builds dynamically input fields based on the specified order of fieldNames http://jsfiddle.net/EdWG3/9/

Comment: However, for building a container that has fields and displays them in a certain order regardless of the template, a better approach would be to build a special model for that. For example a Container object that has an array of Field objects that are bound to other model properties, or something along these lines. This way you could create a generic and flexible template with your system's databinding and manipulation of how everything is displayed.

Comment: other threads that might be useful,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261184/dynamic-value-in-template    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162869/ember-textfield-valuebinding-with-dynamic-property