# Ember js: accessing variables within a {{view}} helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following template where I loop over a list of objects and want to have a checkbox that is bound to a field isChecked for that object. This needs to be in a view helper in order to get the for tag to work (I think). When I do this I can't seem to figure out how to keep the binding with the isChecked field.

```
{{#each listEntry in listEntries}}
    {{#view}}
        {{view Ember.Checkbox viewName="checkboxView" checkedBinding="listEntry.isChecked"}}
        <label {{bindAttr for="view.checkboxView.elementId"}}>Option 1</label>
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is similar to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468164/using-ember-js-text-field-ids-for-a-label-tag), but that approach not work, I think is because the `each` helper.

But [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10507858/1846480) of the comments say about nesting your component in the label.
I have done that and works.

```
{{#each listEntry in listEntries}}
      <label>          
          {{view Ember.Checkbox viewName="checkboxView" checkedBinding="listEntry.isChecked"}}          
          Option 1
     </label>    
  {{/each}}
```

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/RsTCP/) showing

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. What you have helped, but was not exactly what I was looking for. This is mainly because I didn't include enough context in my question. I posted the answer for what I had to do to solve it. There has to be a better way though.

Comment: No problem @DSJ. At least here have 2 approaches to solve this common problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing. The problem I kept having was the need for the binding for the "for" attribute was not working in conjunction with the checked binding. Things were out of scope. If anyone has a better way to accomplish this, please let me know.

```
{{#each listEntry in ListEntries}}
    {{#if ../isCheckable}}
        {{#with ../listEntry}}
            {{#view listEntryBinding="this"}}
                {{view Ember.Checkbox viewName="checkboxView" checkedBinding="listEntry.isChecked"}}
                <label {{bindAttr for="checkboxView.elementId"}}></label>
            {{/view}}
        {{/with}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```